# Does Nosferatu Zodd help Gatsu in the manga?

Tags: berserk

I've just watched the Berserk 1997 series and now I'm watching the 3 part (movie?) from 2012. In the 1997 anime series,

> When Gatsu sword is broken fighting with Boscogne, Nosferatu Zodd gives Gatsu a weapon to continue fighting.

In the 2012 anime,

> Nosferatu Zodd doesnt appear and Gatsu wins the fight on its own

I was wondering how it is the story regarding this in the manga? It's like in the 1997 anime or it's like in the 2012?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **The Battle of Doldrey Chapter 5**,

> Zodd throws down a weapon from somewhere up high, which Guts picked up after Griffith yelled at him to take it.

Also, a quick search on the [wiki](http://berserk.wikia.com/wiki/Boscogn) and looking at the notes on Boscogn's character page will tell the same answer.